# What does the symbol on the bottom of a WotC miniature mean?

Tags: dnd-4e, miniatures, dnd-miniatures-game

When I look on the bottom of the latest official D&D miniatures, there is some information about what product line a particular miniature came from.  But there is also a small symbol below that, like a star or diamond.

I read some where what the symbol meant, but because I have a memory comparable to an Alzheimer's patient, I can't remember.

What do those symbols mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Miniature Rarity,  Circle is common, Diamond is uncommon, Star is rare and Circle-Star is  ultra-rare.